Given the following planetary conditions, what would be the exact length of a year?
List of conditions:

it's an earth-size planet
it's located in a binary star system, where both suns have the same size and mass
the summed up mass of both suns is equivalent to that of our sun
yes, the orbit is stable
there is a moon the same mass as earth's moon, only less dense and therefore, bigger
the distance between the stars is about 5 million km
the distance between the planet in question and the suns is the same as our earth
The masses for both suns are in my notes, I'll add them the minute I find them.

These are elements I'm not willing to change unless you provide solid arguments of them not making any sense.
I've already done some rough calculations to make these things possible, but only in terms of making the orbit stable and for making a planet capable of supporting life. I don't know how to calculate how long would a year be in such a setting and I need this to create a calendar. To be honest, the moon here is a whole different question I'll address later so for your answer please just stick to what I wrote here for the time being. I'll edit later.
Please do ask for more details if you feel the need. I have lots of information but I can't fit it all here without making this post seem messy and overloaded.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you have done all the calculation you should know that to calculate an orbital period we need something which you have not given us: values of masses for the stars and how far the planet orbit them, at least. Plus how far from each other the two star orbit.

Well, I did the calculations to make this star system stable and able to sustain life, but I have no idea of how to calculate the length of the year.

Please give us the distances! We can't make chocolate out of your question if you don't give us the distances.

Oh gosh this is harder than I thought!  But it's going to be worth it

If you don't have the distances I strongly suspect that your calculation on stability can be thrown away.

How have you determined that the orbit is stable? We don’t even know for sure that the Earth’s orbit is stable in the long run, and our solar system is much simpler than yours.

I did not calculate it too deeply, but probably there is no stable orbit so close to use with this configuration. My reasoning is that if the stars are perpendicular to the planet, it will be attracted with an about 1/3600 smaller gravity as if they are parallel. That causes a periodic excitation to its orbit, practically there is no way for this to have a zero effect on the long-term. The orbit of the planet will slowly deviate from the stable nearly-circular orbit, only God can say, exactly how, but the most likely outcome is a stable orbit much more far away (maybe Jupiter distance or so).

Frame challenge
Here's a problem for you:

it's located in a binary star system, where both suns have the same size and mass
the summed up mass of both suns is equivalent to that of our sun

does not square with

the distance between the planet in question and the suns is the same as our earth

The problem is that the luminosity of a star doesn't scale linearly with its mass. A useful approximation is the mass-luminosity relation, which for stars between ~0.43x and 2x the mass of the sun looks like this: $$\frac{L}{L_\odot} \approx \left(\frac{M}{M_\odot}\right)^4$$ where $L$ and $L_\odot$ are the luminosities of your star and the Sun respectively, and $M$ and $M_\odot$ are the masses of your star and the Sun. A star with half the mass of the Sun has approximately 6% of its luminosity. A pair of such stars give you ~12% of the Sun's luminosity, but that's going to leave any world that's a whole AU out feeling very chilly. For specifics of what your stars might look like, have a read up on red dwarfs... a star with half the mass of the Sun would have a classification like M1V.
There are various habitable zone calculators out there (here's one) which you can use to work out how close your world would need to be. A radius of 0.33 to 0.58 AU seems like a reasonable estimate. The orbital period $T$ of a planet around a much larger body of mass $M$ is $T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM}}$ where $a$ is the orbital semi-major axis and $G$ is the gravitational constant. You can handwave your binary stars as a point mass which isn't quite correct here, but it is close enough for your needs. It'll come out as something like 110.26 days at a radius of .45 AU.
Now, since I started typing this you made a comment on L.Dutch's answer suggesting that what you really meant was that the star's combined luminosity was the same as the Sun, even though what you said was that their combined mass was the same.
Now, you can rearrange the mass-luminosity relation to give you the ratio of your star's mass to the Sun... $\sqrt[4]{0.5}$ or about .84 (making them somewhere around a G9V or K0V star). This should let you keep the planet's orbital radius as 1AU, but feeding the new mass into the orbital period equation gives you a year length of more like 281.8 days.

OP is asking the length of the year. This is not answering the question.

@L.Dutch the length of the year is the same as the orbital period, and I calculated that for two possible masses of the central stars. I even finish with the sentence "a year length of more like 281.8 days". What exactly do you feel I have missed from this answer?

@L.Dutch I mean, I even included the orbital period equation in there. I feel like this is a reasonably comprehensive answer that covers the things that the OP probably meant, and provides them with the tools to work it out for themselves if they weren't already aware, which theyt didn't seem to be. That seems like a reasonable answer, no?

There is a lot about the habitability (which OP didn't ask about) and only the rest is about the actual question.

@L.Dutch again, to quote the OP: "I've already done some rough calculations to make these things possible, but only in terms of making the orbit stable and for making a planet capable of supporting life". They clearly do care about habitability, and as such I think it is entirely reasonable for my answer to consider it.

I agree with both of you; this doesn’t actually answer the question, but it does make a very good challenge to the frame.

I have upvoted Starfish Prime's answer.  If L.A. Knight cares about scientific plausibity they may be upset by comments that their planet orbits too far from the star and should really be a frozen wasteland instead of the lush jungle depiced in the story.

I loved it! Numbers hate me and it's reciprocal so it's good to have a site whith people who would the hard math for me! So in that regard, would the day here last as much as an Earth Day? Thank youuu

@L.AKnight for non-tidally-locked planets, the day length can be (more or less) what you'd like. If you'd like it to be the same as an Earth day (from any era) then that's just fine.

Considering that the star mass is the same as our Sun and the distance of the planet is the same as our Earth, in first approximation we can conclude that the orbital period will be equally the same: 1 year.
This because the orbital period is determined by the mass of the primary and the distance from it of the orbiting body.

But there are two closely matched stars instead of one, each half as bright as our Sun. Wouldn't that make their total gravity stronger?

The world will be orbiting the barycentre of the two stars.  Given that their mass sums to the mass of Sol, this should be equivalent... except that two suns each half the mass of our sun will have a much greater surface area than one sun, which if radiation is proportional to surface area means that their combined output will be greater and therefore the planet needs to have a more distant orbit in order to avoid frying.

@L.AKnight your question states "the summed up mass of both suns is equivalent to that of our sun".

@L.AKnight no, the gravity at a sufficient distance from any distribution of masses is the same as if you had a single mass equal to the sum of the available masses, located in the barycenter of the distribution.
If anything, a star half the mass of the Sun would not necessarily be "half as bright". I'd have to make some calculations, but I expect they'd be far less bright, even taken together.

Just as @StarfishPrime pointed out, I've confused mass for brightness, so I my planet would need to be dangerously in the border of the habitable zone then I guess.

I did not calculate it too deeply, but probably there is no stable orbit so close to use with this configuration. My reasoning is that if the stars are perpendicular to the planet, it will be attracted with an about 1/3600 smaller gravity as if they are parallel. That causes a periodic excitation to its orbit, practically there is no way for this to have a zero effect on the long-term. The orbit of the planet will slowly deviate from the stable nearly-circular orbit, only God can say, exactly how, but the most likely outcome is a stable orbit much more far away (maybe Jupiter distance or so).
What can help, if you have luck and the planets orbit is somehow in a synchronous with the stars.

God can be replaced with a numerical simulation in this case ;)

@LazyLizard Well actually scientists playing with these might also have a good clue. But numerical simulations are absolutely not easy in this case. That is because it is a chaotic system, any small deviation from an absolute perfect value cumulates on the long term. For example, no one can say, what will happen to Musk's tesla shot into the space. Hardcore guys could calculate it that is will fall more likely into the Mars as into the Venus in some million years, that is all.

WOW Gray Sheep wouldn't that put my planet far from the inhabitable zone? That's what I interpreted from your phrasing, at least.

@GraySheep The simulation is to see if the system is stable or unstable. Not to calculate the exact position in a billion years.
If you run the simulation for a few million simulated years and the orbit stays in the same place, you can bet it is stable enough.
If it starts to deviate wildly, its not. Does not matter in what way exactly it deviates.

@LazyLizard I think that is right. Probably there are also not very math models to calculate if the system is in a stable point. Logic is, what should be checked: if you give a small perturbation to the system, how will it be affected in the next iterations. Will the perturbation grow or shrink? If it shrinks, we are happy.

About the same as the our Earth, but with more variability.
The length of a sidereal year varies over time due to many factors. See this question. The changes you're making, specifically the binary stars, will likely increase the variability of this value.
All that being said, the general orbital mechanics don't distinguish between orbiting a star, or a barycenter between stars. It's factors other than general gravitation that will make the difference (such as tides, solar wind, the ever changing mass of stars, etc.).

Feel free to revert if you want really so big characters, my suggestion would be roughly this size.
